# Qt Creator does not autocomplete and colorize the code

Tags: c++, qt, autocomplete, qt-creator, syntax-highlighting

I am having a problem with Qt. I am writing C++ code in Qt Creator but it doesn't autocomplete and colorize some of my functions.

Here is the sample of my code:

```
void Form::hide_button(){
    this->ui->pushButton_10->hide();
}

void Form::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    if(push_button_error() == 0){
        if(this->ui->comboBox_6->currentText() == "Evet"){
            open_garph_dialog();
        }
        else{
        }
    }
}
```

For example, it autocompleted `on_pushButton_clicked()` function but it did not complete and colorize other functions. Both functions are defined in the header file.

Do you have any idea why it happened?

Comment: what happens if you go to Help->About_Plugins->ClangCodeModel (change it). And then restart qt creator? does the code completion work then?

Comment: also try Tools->QML/JS->Reset_Code_Model

Comment: Help->About_Plugins->ClangCodeModel (change it) it worked thanks a lot!

Comment: Ok then I will just make it as an answer and you can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Various old Qt Creator versions have this problem. You can fix it with following steps.

1. go to Help
2. select About_Plugins
3. change ClangCodeModel (set or reset)
4. check

Some times the code update in the editor will be stuck, for that you can do following steps to fix it.

1. go to Tools
2. select About_Plugins
3. click Reset_Code_Model